# BackgroungImage of view

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a login screen which has a background image. Initially when i run the application the image does not show up fully and it leaves blank space at the top. When the application is moved to background, and reopened again, the image is shown correctly covering the entire screen. Why this has strange behaviour? I have tried adding uiimageview and settingimge and also setting view's background color with [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: ]. Both does not work fine.. Any solution for this?

Comment: put some relevant code here.

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't use colorWithPatternImage to create an image here, as it uses too much memory while creating image.You will receive memory warnings if you are using large image. Coming to you point , you need to put some of the code here to let us know where are you getting wrong. have you checked the offsets of imageView?

Comment: Even if i dont use any imageview, the initial allignment is not proper. And it changes when i reopen from background.

Comment: Thank u. I fixed the issue. It was because of navigation controller.